# Django filter with 'day-month' together without consider year

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to filter my *datetime* field with 1 month after from today without consider year.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Example filter between: 
**From:** Today Day and Month: 01-05 (%m-%d)
**To:** One Month Later: 02-05 (%m-%d)

Here is my code:

```
        today = datetime.date.today()
        foremonth = today + relativedelta(months=1)
        return_list=[]
        s = Contract.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('date__month', 'date__day')
        for i in s:
            k = i.date.strftime("%m-%d")
            if k > today.strftime("%m-%d") and k < foremonth.strftime("%m-%d"):
                return_list.append(i)
        return return_list
```

**How can I do with django query**

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the Django database functions as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#date-functions), Django [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) and combine them with `Q` to create the query.

1. You results need to fullfill the conditions that either the day is
   greater than your starting day AND the month is our starting month
   OR the day is smaller than your end day AND the month is your end
   month. So we need the day and month values for these conditions.
2. Then we create the query conditions using Q as we need an OR.
3. Finally we annotate the Contract objects with day and month values
   and apply the filter.

```py
    today = datetime.date.today()
    foremonth = today + relativedelta(months=1)

    start_day = today.day
    start_month = today.month
    end_day = foremonth.day
    end_month = foremonth.month

    # Create the query
    query = Q(d__gte=start_day, m=start_month) | Q(d__lte=end_day, m=end_month)

    # Annotate your objects with day and month and filter results

    Contract.objects.annotate(d=ExtractDay('date'), m=ExtractMonth('date')).filter(query)
```